# Cached MX records from Network Solutions..?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, forwarding

The two emails:

**new_email@website.com** ( Previously Network Solutions, now a Google Apps account )
**other_email@other_website.com** ( A Network Solutions email account )

I changed my MX Records for **new_email@website.com** about 7 months ago to point to Google Apps.

Everything works swimmingly, however :

If I set the mail for **other_email@other_website.com** to forward to **new_email@website.com**, then the email gets sent to the old Network Solutions account and not the new Google one, despite the fact that all the MX records clearly only state Google MX Records.

Alternatively, if I were to simply email **new_email@website.com** from **other_email@other_website.com** then it goes through correctly.

This concludes that if any email address is to send to **new_email@website.com**, the MX records appropriately redirect to Google Apps. Unless I am using the forwarding system in Network Solutions. Then the account's MX records are ignored, and it is sent to Network Solutions' default MX records instead.

Does anyone know how to correct this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that it isn't an MX problem as much as NetSOL still has website.com configured in their mail servers, and when other_website.com goes to forward, it bypasses the MX lookup as it is local.  ONly way to fix it would be to get in touch with NetSol and ask Them what is going on.  Not sure if there is some way in their control panel to disable all forms of mail forwarding etc.. That is independent of the MX. but that might work as well.